# German Umlaute Ä Ö Ü in vim

Tags: osx, vim, character-encoding

I'm using the mac-terminal to connect via ssh to my server and my locales on both my server and my mac are set to `de_DE.UTF-8`. Every time I try to enter ö, ä or ü it just writes `Ã¶Ã¤Ã¼` in vim. This happens on my server and local so I think if the problem is solved locally, it can be solved easily on my server.
`:set encode=utf-8` and `:set termencode=utf-8` doesn't change the behaviour, however when I try `:set encode=latin1` instead, it writes the actual `ö`, `ä` and `ü` but it also adds a space after each letter:
`ö ä ü`
My terminal settings are set to utf-8 and several encodings are activated including utf-8 and latin1.

Has anyone any ideas where I can try to solve this awkward problem?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sounds like a Terminal.app issue.  Have you made sure your local settings are correct?  See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24770092/102182

Comment: No problem with umlauts in the terminal itself or other editors?

Comment: Thanks a lot you too! (in nano I had problems with öäü, too (it created 2 newlines and awkward symbols (like a box))) The checkbox was checked, since then everythings works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the help! Following checkbox was the problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770092/102182

"Also, and this is key: under Emulation, make sure that Escape non-ASCII input with Control-V is unchecked (i.e. is not set)."

Big thanks to Mikel!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (VIM in Terminal of Mac OS X 10.5.8. (!!)

in the file `.vimrc`:

```
set encoding=latin1

set filencoding=latin1
```

In Terminal > Preferences > Advanced:

- Escape non-ASCII input
- Strict VT-100
- CharacterEncoding: Western ISO Latin1

Comment: `encoding` wasn't supported in my `nvim` install, but the `fileencoding` option worked nicely.